# Flow + React breaks when capitalizing stateless component

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

## What works

I'm trying to write a stateless component. The following code works and flow says it's ok:

```
import React, { type Node } from 'react';

function renderCond({children}: {children: Array<[boolean, ?Node]>}): ?Node {
  for (const [bool, Component: ?Node] of children) {
    if (bool) {
      return Component;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

<renderCond>
  {[
    [false, <h1>{'Comp 1'}</h1>],
    [true, <h1>{'Comp 2'}</h1>],
    [true, <h1>{'Comp 3'}</h1>],
  ]}
</renderCond>
```

## What doesn't

But, if I search and replace "renderCond" with "RenderCond", flow blows up. Why?

```
3: function RenderCond({children}: {children: Array<[boolean, ?Node]>}): ?Node {
                                                                         ^
all branches are incompatible: Either null or undefined [1] is incompatible with null [2]. Or property `@@iterator` is missing in null or undefined [1] but exists in `$Iterable` [3].

References:
3: function RenderCond({children}: {children: Array<[boolean, ?Node]>}): ?Node {
                                                                         ^ [1]
[LIB] ..//static/v0.93.0/flowlib/react.js:14:   | null
                                                  ^ [2]
[LIB] ..//static/v0.93.0/flowlib/react.js:20:   | Iterable<?React$Node>;
                                                  ^ [3]
```

It works if I `return Component || null` and don't use an optional return type, but I still don't understand why I have to do that. If an optional type is coming in, and I'm returning that optional thing out, why should flow complain that all branches are incompatible?

Even if I `return Component || null` without changing the return type, flow still errors.

flow listed more branches when I ran locally with `flow --show-all-branches`. Why was undefined not in the list?

### TryFlow links

- [renderCond ok](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecYCeYScAchACYkC+cAZlBCHAORSoYsDcAUD3QFcAdhmAQhcdkKpQAwuIoAKHGgAWwADYUp1AFy41m7UiH6AglCgoCAHgDaAIwgQNqIdgD85KgF0AfNQAlPpelCQ4PHD00HCKaOIAzvCOzhrY8uDiJjAh3kg+cBB0cIZaUoG4kVFwwMWKTi4VEdXV7DACUBIZkELZvC3UVYNRbR0SQgIaGryDPDZSMvLSflU4dlVRdnQoGglI2DaqAIx+OCzdcEcs1DYA9Md+PpgbcHYwUAL7cIcnZxcATNc7g8ni83h8vj9TucmGA4ABmIH3E6gqI+QZ3BZIOQKFZAA)
- [RenderCond broken](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecYCeYScAchACYkC+cAZlBCHAORSoYsDcAUD3QFcAdhmAQhiJEKpQAwuIoAKHGgAWwADYV2Q6gC5cazdqkGAglCgoCAHgDaAIwgQNqIdgD85KgF0AfNQAlAZelCQ4PHD00HCKaOIAzvCOzhrY8uDiUjAh3kg+cBB0cEZaOoG4kVFwwMWKTi4VEdXV7DACUBIZkELZvC3UVYNRbR0SQgIaGryDPDbI0khyCn5VOHZVUXZ0KBoJSNg2qgCMfjgs3XDHLNQ2APQnfj6Ym3B2MFACB3BHp+eXACYbvdHs9Xu9Pt9fmcLkwwHAAMzAh6nMFRHyDe4LGTyaSrIA)

Answer (score 0):

The flow system infers `null` differently when `RenderCond` component is written JSX style.

`null` is inferred to be an iterable `React$Node` and shouldn't be hinted as an optional return type.

```
RenderCond({children}: {children: Array<[boolean, ?Node]>}): Node {}
```

Comment: It works if I `return Component || null` and don't use an optional return type, but I still don't understand why I have to do that. If an optional type is coming in, and I'm returning that optional thing out, why should flow complain that all branches are incompatible? Even if I `return Component || null` without changing the return type, flow still errors.It listed more branches when I ran locally with `flow --show-all-branches`. Why was undefined not in the list?

Answer (score 0):

Function components must return a subtype of `React$Node`, which does not include `void`.